# How do I show a ProgressDialog on the UI Thread

Tags: android, progressdialog, ui-thread

I have really been struggling figuring out how to get a ProgressDialog on the UI Thread for this code given that uploadPhoto and would appreciate any guidance:

```
@Override
    /** Handle Upload a Photo **/
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

        // Get image
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Uploading Photo...", true, false);

            switch(requestCode) { 

                // Take Photo
                case 4001:      
                    // Upload
                    uploadPhoto(Uri.fromFile(mImageFile));
                    break;

                // Select Photo
                case 5001:

                    // Get image 
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

                    // Upload
                    uploadPhoto(selectedImage);
                    break;
            }

            // Dismiss
            // dialog.dismiss();            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use AsyncTask may be. put the upload photo function in background of the async task.

start a progress dialog in pre execute.

dismiss/cancel progress dialog in post execute.

post execute and pre execute run on UI thread.

```
private class uploadPhoto extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

            private ProgressDialog dialog;
        protected void onPostExecute(Void dResult) {

                dialog.cancel();

        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {


            dialog = new ProgressDialog(Myactivity.this);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setMessage("uploading...");
            dialog.show();

                }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // call upload photo here.
        }

    }
```

to call the asyncTask use

```
new uploadPhoto().execute();
```

Comment: I kind of understand what you're saying, but I have never done any of these things.

Comment: ok, then you might have to take a look at asyncTask, and how it works. it's generally used for this type of instances. i added some code to let you know how it works.

Answer (score 3):

Use AsyncTask something like this way:

```
public class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<Object , Void, Object> {
    Context context;
    boolean shouldContinue = true;
    public ProgressDialog dialog;
    String waitMessage = "Please wait, loading data...";
    public NetworkTask(Context con){
        this.context = con;     
    }
    public void setMessage(String msg){
        waitMessage = "Please wait, "+msg;
    }
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        shouldContinue  = ConnectionUtils.isNetworkAvailable(context);
        if(shouldContinue)
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, null, waitMessage, true);
        else{
            Dialog.showToast(context, Constants.NETWORK_ERROR);
            return;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result){
        if(dialog != null ){
            if(dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
            dialog = null;
        }           
    }
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params){
        //do uploading and other tasks
    }
}
```

and in your `Activity` call it like this way:

```
NetWorkTask task = new NetWorkTask(this); //Here you can pass other params
task.execute("");
```